# Is it valid to say that $\cos^3(x^{4/3})=\cos(x^4)$?

Tags: trigonometry

As the title says, is it valid to insert the power of the cosine to its angle?
Edit : Is it valid when x is very small ?

Comment: No. They are close near $x=0$ though.

Comment: Had it been $cos(x^{\frac{4}{3}})^{3}$ then you could have

Comment: Notice that $\cos^3(y) \neq \cos(y^3)$, so there's no reason to expect the equation in the question to be true.

Comment: When $x\to 0$, $$\cos^3(x^{4/3})=1-\frac{3}{2}x^{8/3} + o(x^4)$$ while $$\cos(x^4) = 1-\frac{1}{2}x^8 + o(x^8)$$ so the first non-constant terms do not even closely match up.

Answer (score 2):

For $x = \pi^{3/4}$, $\cos^{3}(x^{4/3}) = \cos^{3}(\pi) = -1$. However, $\cos(\pi^{4})\neq -1$, since $\pi^{4}$ can't be a rational multiple of $\pi$ (since $\pi$ is a transcendental number!).

Comment: Although it's pretty much true, I don't think that that's the most helpful approach.

Comment: @rafa11111 I just want to show the simple counter example that just arose in my head :)

Comment: Yes, of course! I just wanted to point out that, IMHO, that's not exactly an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Although
$$
(x^{4/3})^3 = x^4,
$$
one does not have
$$
[f(x^{4/3})]^3=f(x^4)
$$
in general.

[image]

> For your added question "Is it valid when $x$ is very small?":

I assume that you mean when $|x|$ is very small.

No. If these two functions are identical near $x=0$, then they must have the same Taylor expansion. But it is not difficult to see by comparing a few terms that they don't have the same Taylor expansion near $x=0$.

Comment: So this means that this is valid when x is very small ?

Comment: @Johnadams: "close" does not necessarily mean they are "identical". But one can tell that they are identical at $x=0$, of course.